# How can I use arm adcs in loop?

Tags: loops, assembly, arm, bigint, carryflag

In arm assembly language, the instruction `ADCS` will add with condition flags `C` and set condition flags.
And the `CMP` instruction do the same things, so the condition flags will be recovered.
How can I solve it ?
This is my code, it is doing BCD adder with r0 and r1 :

```
    ldr r8, =#0
    ldr r9, =#15
    adds r7, r8, #0

ADDLOOP:
    and r4, r0, r9

    and r5, r1, r9

    adcs r6, r4, r5
    
    orr r7, r6, r7

    add r8, r8, #1
    mov r9, r9, lsl #4

    cmp r8, #3
    bgt ADDEND

    bl ADDLOOP

ADDEND:
    mov r0, r7
```

I tried to save the state of condition flags, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: The easiest solution is to just unroll your loop.  You can also have `r8` count down to zero and use `cbz` or `cbnz` for the conditional branch instead.

Comment: @fuz: IIRC, `cbz`/`cbnz` can only jump forwards, so do ARM `adc` loops tend to end with `cbz .break` / `b .top`?  Or I guess a `while()` structure with a forward `cbz` at the top.  Ah, no, GMP loops like mpn_add_n (https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/arm/aors_n.asm) use `TEQ` which update N and Z but not C or V flags (https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/c/arm-and-thumb-instructions/general-data-processing-instructions/tst-and-teq).  And `mov r9,r9, lsl #4` isn't `movs`, so it won't update the C flag either.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, then `TST` or `TEQ` is indeed a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save/restore the Carry flag, you could create a 0/1 integer in a register (perhaps with `adc reg, zeroed_reg, #0`?), then next iteration `cmp reg, #1` or `rsbs reg, reg, #1` to set the carry flag from it.

ARM can't materialize C as an integer 0/1 with a single instruction without any setup; compilers normally use `movcs r0, #1` / `movcc r0, #0` when not in a loop ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jT4jz7x61)), but in a loop you'd probably want to zero a register once outside the loop instead of using two instructions predicated on carry-set / carry-clear.

---

#### Loop without modifying C

**Use `teq r8, #4` / `bne ADDLOOP` as the loop branch**, like the bottom of a `do{}while(r8 != 4)`.

Or count down from 4 with `tst r8,r8` / `bne ADDLOOP`, using `sub r8, #1` instead of add.

`TEQ` updates `N` and `Z` but not C or V flags.  (Unless you use a shifted source operand, then it can update C).  [docs](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0489/c/arm-and-thumb-instructions/general-data-processing-instructions/tst-and-teq) - unlike `cmp`, it sets flags like `eors`.  The `eq` / `ne` conditions work the same: subtraction and XOR both produce zero when the inputs are equal, and non-zero in every other case.  But `teq` doesn't even set C or V flags, and greater / less wouldn't be meaningful anyway.

This is what optimized BigInt code like GMP does, for example in its `mpn_add_n` function ([source](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mpn/arm/aors_n.asm)) which adds two bigint inputs (arrays of 32-bit chunks).

IDK why you were jumping forwards over a `bl` (branch-and-link) which sets lr as a return address.  Don't do that, structure your asm loops like a `do{}while()` [because it's more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783926/why-are-loops-always-compiled-into-do-while-style-tail-jump), especially when the trip-count is known to be non-zero so you don't have to worry about running the loop zero times in some cases.

---

There are `cbz`/`cbnz` instructions ([docs](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/arm-and-thumb-instructions/cbz-and-cbnz)) that jump on a register being zero or non-zero without affecting flags, but they can only jump forwards (out of the loop, past an unconditional branch).  They're also only available in Thumb mode, unlike `teq` which was probably specifically designed to give ARM an efficient way to write BigInt loops.

---

#### BCD adding

Your algorithm has bugs; you need base-10 carry, like `0x05 + 0x06` = `0x11` not `0x0b` in packed BCD.

And even the binary Carry flag isn't set by something like `0x0005000 + 0x0007000`; there's no carry-out from the high bit, only into the next nibble.  Also, `adc` adds the carry-in at the bottom of the register, not at nibble your mask isolated.

So maybe you need to do something like subtract `0x000a000` from the sum (for that example shift position), because that will carry-out.  (ARM sets C as a !borrow on subtraction, so maybe `rsb` reverse-subtract or swap the operands.)

---

NEON should make it possible to unpack to 8-bit elements (mask odd/even and interleave) and do all nibbles in parallel, but carry propagation is a problem; ARM doesn't have an efficient way to branch on SIMD vector conditions (unlike x86 `pmovmskb`).  Just byte-shifting the vector and adding could generate further carries, as with `999999 + 1`.

IDK if this can be cut down effectively with the same techniques hardware uses, like [carry-select](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-select_adder) or [carry-lookahead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder), but for 4-bit BCD digits with SIMD elements instead of single bits with hardware full-adders.

It's not worth doing for binary bigint because you can work in 32 or 64-bit chunks with the carry flag to help, but maybe there's something to gain when primitive hardware operations only do 4 bits at a time.